# how to set accessoryType when cell has been selected

Tags: iphone, ios, accessorytype

I have been trying to figure out how to set the accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark when the cell is selected but am having trouble finding a decent example of this.

If you know how to do this or a good tutorial could you please let me know that would be great.

Comment: [**Here**](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uitableviewcontroller-by-example.aspx) is a very nice example for UITableView and UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To restrict the user to just one selection, meaning to create an exclusive list of one choice only, you could follow these steps;

Firstly, have a global index path declared in your .h file to keep track of the already selected cell ->

```
NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath;
```

When you create the cells, be sure to set the accessory type to none, so that no cell is selected by default when the table is seen;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CallIdentifier"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;      
    }
    return cell; 
}
```

Finally, in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method, add the following code which will remove the checkmark from the already selected cell, and add a checkmark to the newly selected one.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (oldIndexPath==nil) { // No selection made yet
        oldIndexPath=indexPath;
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *formerSelectedcell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath]; // finding the already selected cell
        [formerSelectedcell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark]; // 'select' the new cell
        oldIndexPath=indexPath;
    }   
}
```

Hope this works out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

To answer the comment below, just push a viewController in the same method like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    // Then push a new view
    iPhoneCustomViewController *myVC = [[iPhoneCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneCustomViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
    [myVC release];

    // And deselect the row (if desired)
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: this one worked well, I changed the [self tableview:mytab... to [self.tableview .. etc and it worked well.. how would I restrict the user to one selection? would I just push the new view or is there a better way of handling it?

Comment: Yea, just push a new view in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.  I don't think you can have multiple selections anyway unless the table allows editing and table.isEditing is true.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that:

1.) UITableView keeps track of the index paths for the rows that have been selected? It's in an array called indexPathsForSelectedRows

2.) UITableView has a flag you can set to make it either single or multiple selection. You can change it by calling the setter setAllowsMultipleSelection:(BOOL).

So, assuming that the table has been set to single selection, we can do the following in the tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath method ...

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Some Text"];

NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

if ([selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}else{
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}

return cell;}
```

This implementation of CellForRowAtIndexPath will give you a clean checkmark with no gray background when a cell is selected. You will need to set the checkmark in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method to make sure a cell gets the checkmark the moment it gets selected.

No need to create separate ivars or anything else to keep track of what was or wasn't selected. It's all neatly contained in the UITableView as Apple intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 newCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Implement this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a):

> The delegate handles selections in this method. One of the things it
>   can do is exclusively assign the check-mark image
>   (UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) to one row in a section
>   (radio-list style). This method isn’t called when the editing property
>   of the table is set to YES (that is, the table view is in editing
>   mode). See "Managing Selections" in Table View Programming Guide for
>   iOS for further information (and code examples) related to this
>   method.

Here is an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
   cell.UITableViewAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```